# How to show transparent section on top of another section on hover event in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to show an transparent layer containing text, button and link on hover event of another section/div. Do I need to write custom code with events that will change styling of elements at runtime with help of **ng-style** taglib? or Is there any better alternative to achieve this?

Comment: You could probably use a combination of [ng-mouseover](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover) and [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: @Evgeny & deadManN- This will help me to achieve only show and hide feature. I don't want to hide parent section. I want to show **transparent** overlay of other section on parent section.

Comment: At least I'm having a hard time understanding what you're aiming for. Can you supply us with some code or a picture to help us understand what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Just use css hover and change opacity (note the transition is optional but can make for a nice effect).

#### html

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="title">hover text</div>

</div>
```

#### css

```
.wrapper { border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 200px; height: 200px; }

.title { opacity : 0; transition: opacity .5s ease-in }

.wrapper:hover .title { opacity : 1 }
```

#### fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/215crow2/1/

Answer (score 0):

in your control define a variable:
`$scope.showContainer=false;`
or inside your HTML in upper tag of both container and button
`<div ng-init="showContainer=false">`

and then just as Fissio Said, use mouseenter and mouseleave

```
mouseenter=> showContainer= true
mouseleave=> showCOntainer= false
```

`<div class="container" ng-show="showContainer"> ... </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate:

**html:**

```
<div ng-mouseenter="setFunction(true)" ng-mouseleave="setFunction(false)" >
    //this is your main content here

   <div ng-class="isTransparent">
      //your transparent overlay div
   </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.myClass{
your overlay transparency styles here.
}
```

**angular:**

```
$scope.setFunction= function (val) {

   if (val === true) {
       $scope.isTransparent = 'myClass'; //note you may need a dot in fromt of myClass: '.myClass'
   }
   else {
       $scope.isTransparent = '';
   }
};
```

Comment: So you want to apply the styles to a div when hovering over another div and then remove them?

Comment: //note you may need a dot in fromt of myClass: '.myClass'

Comment: my experience of using mouse enter and leave event is that it doesn't always work properly if your really quick with the mouse and have lots of elements that you enter and leave sometimes state thinks you havent left it when you have - best to use css `:hover` and change `opacity`